# Can i develop UWP program using windows 7 and visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-7, windows-10, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi3 with windows 10 IoT and my pc has windows 7. I can't use the XAMP Editor in visual studio 2015 because i need to upgrade my pc to windows 10... Is there a way to develop the app using windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted on the VS 2015 [system requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-sysrequirements-vs)

```
For Windows Store and Windows Universal app development: Windows 8.1 and
Windows Phone 8.1 development require Windows 8.1 Update or later.
```

IOW: Windows 8.1 (fully updated) or Windows 10 is required to develop a UWP.

> With VS 2017, UWP development requires Windows 10. See [VS 2017 system requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs)